# How to save the last captured date for data extraction in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, stored-procedures, data-extraction

I have procedure which will extract the data from remote database `SOAP_MONITORING` table to the local database `TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING` table for every 5 min.The ID in the `SOAP_MONITORING@FOINC_RETAIL` table are sequence generated. I am storing the max ID in the capturing table and extract the data with id greater than for the next 5 min extraction so that i will always get the latest data.In the `Capturing` table i have saved the date timestamp when the extraction performed in the `CAPTURED_DATE` column. The only thing now i want to do is i also want to save the date time for the last extraction done in the `LAST_CAPTURED_DATE` column, so that i can easily check how much time it took for data extraction using this two columns. Here is my Capturing table:

```
ID  DB    DB_TABLE              LAST_TASK_ID        CAPTURED_DATE             LAST_CAPTURED_DATE   
181 FONIC TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING 201504211002095052   21.04.15 10:03:06         NULL
```

Here is my procedure:

```
PROCEDURE "EXT_SOAP_MONITORING" AS 
LAST_SM_ID Number := 0;

BEGIN

--DELETE DATA FROM TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING';

-- first retrieve the last id (of the newest record) which has been emportet at last extraction
SELECT LAST_TASK_ID INTO LAST_SM_ID FROM CAPTURING where DB_TABLE='TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING';

-- retrieve all new records from remote SOAP_MONITORING and insert it into TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING using MERGE statement
-- MERGE statement is able to retrieve CLOB fields:

merge into TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING TSM
using (
   select * from
(select ID,REQUEST_XML,RESPONSE_XML,WEB_SERVICE_NAME,WEB_METHOD_NAME,CREATE_DATE,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE from 
SOAP_MONITORING@FONIC_RETAIL WHERE WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService' and WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder' and ID > LAST_SM_ID order by ID desc) 
) data
ON (TSM.ID = data.ID)
when not matched then
insert(ID,REQUEST_XML,RESPONSE_XML,WEB_SERVICE_NAME,WEB_METHOD_NAME,CREATE_DATE,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE)
values(data.ID,data.REQUEST_XML,data.RESPONSE_XML,data.WEB_SERVICE_NAME,data.WEB_METHOD_NAME,data.CREATE_DATE,data.ERROR_CODE,data.ERROR_MESSAGE);



-- Set the newest extracted ID as LAST_TASK_ID for TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING in the Capturing table
update
CAPTURING set LAST_TASK_ID= 
CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(ID) from TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING) IS NULL THEN LAST_TASK_ID + 1 ELSE (SELECT MAX(ID) from TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING) END,
CAPTURING_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where DB_TABLE='TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING';

END EXT_SOAP_MONITORING1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can do it very similar how you did it for variable `LAST_SM_ID`. 
Declare variable, get last value in `select` where you retrieved `LAST_TASK_ID` and add line in `update` statement.

```
PROCEDURE "EXT_SOAP_MONITORING" AS 
LAST_SM_ID Number := 0;
LAST_SM_DATE Timestamp;                         -- add this variable
BEGIN

...

-- store CAPTURED_DATE into variable LAST_SM_DATE
SELECT LAST_TASK_ID, CAPTURED_DATE INTO LAST_SM_ID, LAST_SM_DATE 
  FROM CAPTURING where DB_TABLE='TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING';

...

update CAPTURING set 
    LAST_TASK_ID= 
      CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(ID) from TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING) IS NULL THEN LAST_TASK_ID + 1 
           ELSE (SELECT MAX(ID) from TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING) END,
    CAPTURING_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    LAST_CAPTURED_DATE = LAST_SM_DATE          -- update here
  where DB_TABLE='TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING';

END EXT_SOAP_MONITORING1;
```